# Hiding a google search option

Tags: javascript

Trying to hide the google microphphone; the class element "JC0tCe" is used for this. Should this work?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Remove Google microphone
// @include     https://www.google.com/*
// @version     1.0
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

var pushdown = document.getElementsByClassName('.JC0tCe');
if (pushdown) {
    pushdown.parentNode.removeChild(pushdown);
}
var promo = document.querySelector(".JC0tCe");
    promo.parentNode.removeChild(promo);
```

Comment: Looks like a generated class name. It may or may not work the next time a new version of the site is deployed.

Comment: Seem static enough for the moment

Comment: Tried this also;var microphone = document.getElementsByClassName('JC0tCe');
    microphone.display = 'none';

Comment: `document.querySelector('[aria-label="Search by voice"]')` would likely be more reliable, to add to @FelixKling's comment

Comment: @JanetD it's `.style.display`, not `.display`

Comment: What's the deal with the `getElementsByClassName` ? It returns an HTMLCollection not an element/node

Comment: var promo = document.querySelector('[aria-label="Search by voice"]');
    promo.parentNode.removeChild(promo);  like so?

Comment: @zfrisch As the name implies, it returns *all* elements with the specified class name. You would need to do something like `document.getElementsByClassName("class")[0]` to get the first element.

Comment: @BenjaminSoyka lol, sorry for the misunderstanding. I know. That's why I was asking why OP was trying to use it like he was.

Comment: @zfrisch Ah, alright. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
document.querySelector('[aria-label="Search by voice"]').style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

It searches for the element with the `aria-label` of `"Search by voice"`, which is the microphone icon. Then, it makes that invisible.